Unable to change Overflow icon color in my Toolbar
In my gradle I'm using material 1.12 acording to various article it is somehow possible to style the threedots icon used as overflow menu for my toolbar (top) this is what I have defined in my style, as you can see I have set various colors to try hit the right one:
<style name="App.Theme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/App.Theme.Popup</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/App.Theme.Popup</item>
</style>

<style name="App.Theme.Popup" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/PopupMenuStyle</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#ffff00</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">#00ffff</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>

    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:tint">#fff</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenuStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:iconTint">#fff</item>
</style>

The overflow icon color remains unchanged, however if I set App.Theme.Popup directly on my Toolbar layout, it works. This suggest me the property toolbarStyle and android:actionBarStyle are ignored and the theme is not correctly linked.
How can I set the color for the overflow menu icon, using themes?
